# Better Performance with single thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm doing a tree search for a class assignment. I understand the tree search part, but as I have some extra time, I wanted to speed it up by adding more threads.

The final task is to take in a set of constraints, classes and time-slots, and output a schedule with all those classes, and which satisfies all the constraints. An empty or partial assignment goes in, a complete class assignment comes out.

Our search is designed like a tree, with the input being the root node. The function `div(n)` is as follows: for a node `n`, find an unused class C, and for each unused slot S, produce a child node with C in S. To make the search more efficient, we use a search control which ranks the quality of nodes, so that the best candidates are selected first, and we don't waste time on bad candidates

A node implements Comparable, with `compareTo()` implemented using the search control. I use a priority queue to store nodes awaiting processing, so the 'best' nodes are always next in line. A worker removes an node, applies `div()` and adds the children to the priority queue.

My first approach was using a shared priority queue, specifically `PriorityBlockingQueue`. The performance was abysmal, since the queue was almost always blocking.

I tried to fix it by adding a background worker and a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` buffer. workers would add to the buffer, and the the worker would periodically move elements from the buffer to the priority queue. This didn't work either.

The best performance I have found is to give each worker it's own priority queue. I'm guessing that this is as good as it gets, as now threads aren't connected to the actions of others. with this config, on an 4C/8T machine, I get a speedup  of ~2.5. I think the bottleneck here is the allocation of memory for all these nodes, but I could be wrong here.

From Searcher:

```
private PriorityQueue<Schedule> workQueue;
private static volatile boolean shutdownSignal = false;
private Schedule best;

public Searcher(List<Schedule> instances) {
    workQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(instances);
}

public static void stop() {
    shutdownSignal = true;
}

/**
 * Run the search control starting with the first node in the workQueue
 */
@Override
public void run() {

    while (!shutdownSignal) {
        try {
            Schedule next = workQueue.remove();
            List<Schedule> children = next.div(checkBest);
            workQueue.addAll(children);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
    //For testing
    System.out.println("Shutting down: " + workQueue.size());
}

//passing a function as a parameter
Consumer<Schedule> checkBest = new Consumer<Schedule>() {
    public void accept(Schedule sched) {
        if (best == null || sched.betterThan(best)) {
            best = sched;
            Model.checkBest.accept(sched);
        }
    }
};
```

From Schedule:

```
public List<Schedule> div(Consumer<Schedule> completion) {
    List<Schedule> n = new ArrayList<>();

    int selected = 0;
    List<Slot> available = Model.getSlots();
    List<Slot> allocated = getAssigned();

    while (allocated.get(selected) != null) {
        selected++;
    } // find first available slot to fill.
      // Iterate through all available slots
    for (Slot t : available) {
        //Prepare a fresh copy
        List<Slot> newAssignment = new ArrayList<>(allocated.size());
        Collections.copy(newAssignment, allocated);

        //assign the course to the timeslot
        newAssignment.set(selected, t);
        Schedule next = new Schedule(this, newAssignment);
        n.add(next);
    }

    /**
     * Filter out nodes which violate the hard constraints and which are solved, 
     * and check if they are the best in a calling thread
     */

    List<Schedule> unsolvedNodes = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Schedule schedule: n) {
        if (schedule.constr() && !schedule.solved()){
            unsolvedNodes.add(schedule);
            completion.accept(schedule);
        }
    }
    return unsolvedNodes;
}
```

Comment: You will get deadlock if your `workQueue` get full. Next thread trying to add something will be blocked. All other thread will be blocked to so there will be no one to remove node from queue.

Comment: What is your question? If it is "Why?" then there is not enough data. We need to know what `div` method do?

Comment: I apologize, yes, my question is Why.

Div takes some node. and applies a non-trivial process to produce children nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that fork-join framework is an appropriate tool for your task. You need to extend your task from either [ResursiveTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveTask.html) or [ResursiveAction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveAction.html) and submit it to [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html). Here is a pseudo-code sample. Also your `shutdown` flag must be `volatile`.

```
public class Task extends RecursiveAction {
    private final Node<Integer> node;

    public Task(Node<Integer> node) {
      this.node = node;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {
      // check result and stop recursion if needed

      List<Task> subTasks = new ArrayList<>();

      List<Node<Integer>> nodes = div(this.node);
      for (Node<Integer> node : nodes) {
        Task task = new Task(node);
        task.fork();
        subTasks.add(task);
      }

      for(Task task : subTasks) {
        task.join();
      }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node root = getRootNode();
        new ForkJoinPool().invoke(new Task(root));
    }
```

Comment: I was using a priority queue to select the 'Best' node to work on next. I don't understand how this would provide the same functionality.

Comment: I think you should spend some time to get acquainted with this type of pool to fully understand how it works. Number of threads equals to configured `parallelism` process incoming tasks. Each thread has its own queue with tasks. It's possible to read from both sides of the queue. When `fork` is invoked new task is added to the head of some thread queue. Each thread reads tasks from the head of its queue. When thread finishes processing tasks from its own queue it steals tasks from tail of other threads queues. Task which invokes `join` waits for result from children task.

Comment: Part of the assignment is using a search control to pick and choose which nodes to process next, as the search tree may be very large. 

The search control is to pick the globally best node to be the next one to be processed. Hence the priority queue. I think I understand how fork join works, and how it could be put to use. 
I am hesitating however, because, here, even if div sorts it's output first, that 'chunk' may contain a global optimum which will not be present in the task queue further up. This would effectively ignore our search control.

Comment: I got your point. Nevertheless i would advise you to test it with various configurations. If your div method returns nodes based on priority they will be processed in that order because more prioritized tasks are forked/processed earlier. This rule applies to all parallel threads, so i believe you can achieve performance impact with appropriate `parallelism` level.

Comment: Allow me to clarify. So what you are saying is that by achieving a sufficient level of parallelism, it may be faster than using my search control? If so, then yes, I am sure that that may be the case, however that's not really the spirit of the assignment.

I guess what I'm having difficulty with is that suppose there are 500 nodes in the task queue at some point. The next task that is processed produces a global max node, with 7 siblings, even if we sort the list, that global max is now (500/`paralellism`) in line, not first.

Comment: @SEMANTICALLY_INVALID it would be nice to get/understand more context about your task, can we continue conversation in chat ? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159087/47300661

Comment: I would like to continue this in chat, however I appear to be 4 reputation short. Is there another communication channel you would be ok using?

Comment: ah, could you describe your algorithm in more detail, how is it possible to find the node with the highest priority in the middle of processing? It would be nice to get some code samples

Comment: I've modified my question to add more information / update what I've tried.

Comment: Do you start all Searchers with the same root node ?

Comment: no. I div them up until there are more nodes than threads, and assign them round robin to the threads.

Comment: Presence of a separate queue for each thread seems like a signal for fork join pool. Try to implement it using `TreeSet` as return result from div and make some measurements. It would be interesting to get actual numbers.